# Swift4, Background Color when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am attempting to highlight the background of a cell when a user selects it. 
I have been successful in changing the border of a cell when a user selects it.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    addToList.append(objectsArray[indexPath.row])
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell?.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
```

I have not been able to change the background though.

Can this be done?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried something like `cell?.backgroundColor = .red`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For cell border, use `cell` `contentView` like this:**

```
cell?.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
cell?.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

And for cell `backgroundColor` color you need to use:

```
cell?.backgroundColor = .gray
```

Comment: Please note: question was how to change the *background colour*, the border colour has already been changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```